# AspectJ confusion with pointcut

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, pointcuts

How can I express a point cut that finds methods only when being called from within another method, but not directly?

For example:

```
Foo() calls Bar() calls object.Method()
```

also

```
NotFoo() calls Bar() calls object.Method()
```

I only want the pointcut to work for within Foo()

I tried "withincode," but that seems to only work directly.

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want actually requires two joinpoints:

1. `call` method or constructor in Bar class and be `within` Foo class or eventually Foo() constructor with `withincode` designator. The advice to this joinpoint can for example set a flag that to true when called from Foo() and falso otherwise. This variabel can be stored in a HashMap with the thread as key to avoid concurrency issues.
2. `withincode` Bar() constructor or within Bar class and `call` object.Method(). The advice to this joinpoint must also check if the flag is set to true. And finally set the Foo flag to false again.

Comment: I think cflow and cflowbelow are just made to handle this type of flagging in the execution flow.